# C++ warning C4800 - 'int' forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' with switch statement

Tags: c++, warnings, boolean

In this segment of code, `toPurchase` is converted from an integer to a bool when it is initialised with `player->giveOptions()` (which returns an integer, not a boolean) very near the end of this code. After, there is a `switch(toPurchase)`, which then the compiler says won't work because `toPurchase` has been converted to a bool. Why?

```
int loc = player->giveOptions(4,"Trainers","Market","Inn","Back","");
    int chos;
    bool success = true;
    bool toPurchase = false;
    switch(loc){
    case 1:
        text.push_back("Hello, "+player->name+".");
        if (player->firstTrainerVisit){
            text.push_back("I'm not sure if anyone's told you, but there's been some strange talk about you lately...");
            text.push_back("Hmm... A lot of people are scared of you.");
            text.push_back("Anyway, nice to meet you. I'm Yobbee, the village trainer.");
            text.push_back("You'll need training up before meeting the village elders.");
            text.push_back("Usually, you need to pay to get trained by me, but as a first time bonus I'll teach you for free.");
            text.push_back("After you've been trained, you get a skill point, which you can use to increase one of your abilities.");
        }
        text.push_back("Would you like to be trained today?");
        NPCTalk("Yobbee (Trainer)",text);
        text.clear();
        chos = player->giveOptions(2,"Yes","No","","","");
        switch(chos){
        case 1:
            if(!player->firstTrainerVisit){
                cout << "This will cost 10 gold. Continue?" << endl;
                int purchase = player->giveOptions(2,"Yes","No","","","");
                if(purchase)
                    success = player->spendGold(5);
                else
                    success = false;
            }
            if (success){
                player->awardStat(1,"sp");
                cout << "After a day of vigorous training, you find your skills honed." << endl;
            }else{
                cout << "You don't have enough gold!" << endl;
            }
            if(player->firstTrainerVisit&&success){
                text.push_back("You can use your skill point to increase one of your stats by typing 'sp' any time you are given a choice.");
                text.push_back("There are other commands you can use at any choice opportunity as well - just type 'help' to see this one and others.");
                NPCTalk("Yobbee (Trainer)",text);
                text.clear();
                player->firstTrainerVisit = false;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        }
        cout << "\nBack to the entrance to Poglathon..." << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        Poglathon(text,player);
        break;
    case 2:
        if(player->firstMarketVisit){
            text.push_back("Oh... Hello, "+player->name+".");
            text.push_back("Ignore other people's looks. You'll find out about all this when you meet the Elders.");
            if(!player->firstElderVisit) text.push_back("Oh, you have already? Then I don't feel guilty about not explaining.");
            text.push_back("Here, at the market, you can buy new equipment for your travels, such as food, weapons and armour.");
            text.push_back("You don't have any gold at the moment, but as a standard first-time visit we will issue you with some leather armour and a rusty dagger.");
            text.push_back("Not the best of items, but it'll certainly help!");
            text.push_back("The weapon and armour are now in your backpack. To equip items in your backpack, when you are given an option type 'backpack'.");
            player->addToBackpackIfSpace("Rusty dagger");
            player->addToBackpackIfSpace("Leather armour");
            NPCTalk("Market Manager",text);
            text.clear();
            player->firstMarketVisit = false;
        }
        cout << "Do you want to purchase anything at the market?" << endl;
        toPurchase = player->giveOptions(2,"Yes","No","","","");
        switch(toPurchase){
        case 1:
            cout << "You can't purchase anything yet. NOOB" << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        }
        cout << "\nBack to the entrance to Poglathon..." << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        Poglathon(text,player);
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you switch on `toPurchase`, which is in fact boolean (declared as boolean in line 4)

Comment: WHAT, I DECLARED `toPurchase` AS A BOOL?! That's annoying, I spend ages trying to figure that out. How did I not notice that?

Answer (score 2):

Simply change this code:

```
switch(toPurchase){
    case 1:
        cout << "You can't purchase anything yet. NOOB" << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    }
```

to:

```
if (toPurchase)
{
    cout << "You can't purchase anything yet. NOOB" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a statically typed language. You have declared toPurchase as a bool variable, so it will remain bool until you violently cast is to something else. But manual casting is not recommended.

Although, int can be casted implicitly to bool, and this happens at

    `toPurchase = player->giveOptions(2,"Yes","No","","","");`

.

This value assignent doesn't change the type of toPurchase like it would do in php for example. It casts the return value of giveOptions to bool, and assigns that casted bool value to to Purchase.